# How do you close a pull request in python?

Tags: python, gitpython

I created a pull request using

```
github_repo.create_pull(base='master', head=branch_name, title='title')
```

I can't seem to find how to close one.

Comment: Didn't find method `create_pull` in tagged [tag:gitpython] package. Did you use package [`PyGithub`](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/), then please [edit] your question and use the tag [tag:PyGithub], link the packaged used and add respective import statements in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref the PyGitHub code:

https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/PullRequest.py

See GitHub API, resource "Pulls", [Update a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-pull-request) for query parameter `state`

> **`state`** string
>
> Either `open`, `closed`, or `all` to filter by state.
>
> Default: `open`

I'd say you want to update the PR with query-parameter as`state=closed`:

```
pr = ??? Code to get the PR you want ???
pr.edit(state="closed")
```

Comment: For future readers, it looks like this is now using `state` rather than `status`, but otherwise I suspect this still works.

Comment: What's the purpose of the code-line reference link below "Ref the PyGitHub code:" ?

Answer (score 0):

To close a PR with package [`PyGithub`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub) use [`Repository.get_pull()`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html?highlight=create_pull#github.Repository.Repository.get_pull) to return an instance of [`PullRequest`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/PullRequest.html#github.PullRequest.PullRequest), then [`PullRequest.edit(state='closed')`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/PullRequest.html#github.PullRequest.PullRequest.edit).

```py
# either create a PR within given repo and return the instance
pr = github_repo.create_pull(base='master', head=branch_name, title='title')
print(pr.id)

# or get the PR instance by PR id
id = pr.id
pr = github_repo.get_pull(id)

# to close it update the PR with state=closed 
pr.edit(state='closed')
print('PR was closed at: ', pr.closed_at)
```

Comment: I am getting 404 error with this code. 404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls/#update-a-pull-request"}

Comment: Update on the above comment- It seems that one should have appropriate access to the repositories/ org repositories otherwise it wont work. I tried it on my personal github repo and it worked fine. Thanks